# Add flag to document during querying

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am wanting to add a flag to each class document returned if the `req.user._id` exists in the `mentors.mentorList` array. And if the mentor exists within the `mentors.mentorList`, set a flag to `isMentor:true` OR `isMentor:false` respectively.

*I am seeing if there is an alternative to manipulating the returned `classes` documents.*

My query is the following:

```js
  Class.find({
            schools: { $in: schools },
            $or: [
              { "mentors.mentorList": { $size: 0 } },
              { "mentors.mentorList": { $in: req.user._id } }
            ]
          })
            .populate()
            .then(classes => {  <---- Can I add the flag to each item in classes?
                     ....      

                     })
```

Comment: you can use **`$addFields`**, read more in mongo docs.

Comment: @niranjanharpale I’ll do that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.